# Is there a way to use CLI to POST data on django2 project?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, command-line-interface

I have a webapp that I created using Django2. At a high level, it will be used to process .tsv files of data and display them nicely on a screen.

I want to be able to have a command line interface where I can perform a POST request to the already running webapp, and essentially add data to a model, save it, and create a unique webpage to display that data. Something like:

```
uploadtodjangoapp <myfilename> --user='heidi' --other-options='....'
uploading myfilename to myapp!
done
see data here: www.mysite.com/info/myfilename
```

In this situation ^ the webpage will be running already somewhere (either locally or on a vm).

Currently, I know you can create a form on the user interface to perform post requests/get user data. And I know you can also use `python manage.py shell` and do something like:

```
>> from myapp.model import mymodel
>> m = mymodel(data="some data here")
>> m.save()
```

.... but is this the only way?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can define your own command, to for example load data in bulk, etc. see for example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: You don't have to use Django to make an HTTP POST to a Django application. You can simply use an existing tool such as [`curl`](https://ec.haxx.se/http-post.html) to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using curl

Just for Example :
In terminal

```
curl --data "field_1=data_1&field_2=data_2&field_3=data_3" <API FOR POST REQUEST>
```